# Esx 5.5 how to link vswitch1 with vswitch0?

Tags: vmware-esx, vswitch

I am not so good in virtual networking.
The problem that I'm facing now is, I have 2 vswitches, vswitch1 and vswitch0.

Vswitch0 has internet access and public ip.
Vswitch1 has no adapter and has been assigned private ip.

So, the question is, how to make VM in vswitch1 can ping to VM in vswitch0?

My plan is, webserver will be put on vswitch0 and database server will be put on vswitch1.

So, can you guys help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach is slightly different than you describe.

Typically you would place the webserver on vswitch0 AND vswitch1, with the database server on vswitch1.  It would look like:

```
client
  |
Internet
  |
vswitch0
  |
web server
  |
vswitch1
  |
database
```

This permits your web server and database to chat, and the client and the web server to chat, but prevents the client from chatting with the database.

Comment: Thanks. The VM should have 2 LAN port. 1 for vswitch0 and 1 for vswitch1. I have tested it and it works perfectly!